# Practice Problems Schema Warnings

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, structured-data

During audit of the web property in search console, there is warning in practice problem schema

> Missing field "comment", Missing field "assesses", Missing field "educationalLevel", Missing field "typicalAgeRange"

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org",
   "@type":"ImageObject",
   "url":"https://doubtnut-static.s.llnwi.net/static/q-thumbnail/642813389.png"
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org/",
   "@type":"Quiz",
   "name":"Quiz about प्राकृतिक संसाधनों का प्रबंधन",
   "about":"प्राकृतिक संसाधनों का प्रबंधन",
   "url":"https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer-biology/ek-hii-phsl-ko-usii-khet-men-baar-baar-ugaane-kii-kriyaa-ko-khte-hain-644913408",
   "educationalAlignment":[
      {
         "@type":"AlignmentObject",
         "alignmentType":"educationalSubject",
         "targetName":"Biology"
      }
   ],
   "hasPart":{
      "@type":"Question",
      "typicalAgeRange":"11-18",
      "educationalLevel":"intermediate",
      "eduQuestionType":"Multiple choice",
      "learningResourceType":"Practice problem",
      "assesses":"प्राकृतिक संसाधनों का प्रबंधन",
      "name":"Question about प्राकृतिक संसाधनों का प्रबंधन",
      "comment":{
         "@type":"Comment",
         "text":"Watch complete video answer for “गेहूँ और मूंगफली को एक ही खेत में साथ-साथ उगाने को कहते हैं .” of Biology Class 10th. Get FREE solutions to all questions from chapter प्राकृतिक संसाधनों का प्रबंधन."
      },
      "text":"गेहूँ और मूंगफली को एक ही खेत में साथ-साथ उगाने को कहते हैं ................|",
      "encodingFormat":"text/markdown",
      "suggestedAnswer":[
         {
            "@type":"Answer",
            "encodingFormat":"text/markdown",
            "text":"एपीकल्चर",
            "position":1
         },
         {
            "@type":"Answer",
            "encodingFormat":"text/markdown",
            "text":"मोनोकल्वर ",
            "position":2
         },
         {
            "@type":"Answer",
            "encodingFormat":"text/markdown",
            "text":"सिल्वीकल्चर",
            "position":3
         },
         {
            "@type":"Answer",
            "encodingFormat":"text/markdown",
            "text":"सैरीकल्चर ",
            "position":4
         }
      ],
      "acceptedAnswer":[
         {
            "@type":"Answer",
            "encodingFormat":"text/markdown",
            "text":"मोनोकल्वर ",
            "position":2,
            "answerExplanation":{
               "@type":"Comment",
               "text":"मोनोकल्वर ",
               "encodingFormat":"text/markdown"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}</script>
```

And There are lots of pages facing same issues. How to do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you looked through Google's documentation? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/practice-problems

Comment: Yes its works we resolved it! thank you!